# show html message on generic javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to show a html message on a generic javascript error?

For example when a variable does not exist or is empty (after a jQuery call to a database), I get an error message in the browser console.

Is there a general way to catch these errors and display a html message for the user?

I know that I can do specific checks in this case, but I was wondering if there is a general method to catch any javascript error and then use that to display a message for the user.

Comment: `window.onerror = function(e) { ... }` will catch any otherwise uncaught errors.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but usually if it is an HTTP request I would wrap it in a `try...catch` block, see more about [try-catch here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) then log out the error.

Something like this:

```
try {
  // Do the database call...
} catch (error) {
  // Do something with the error, like show a HTML message.
  console.log(error.name, error.message);
}
```

The API for a generic error can be found here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, it is not the database call that may fail. It is rather that an entry does not exist in the database, but the code assumes it exists (which leads to an error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" – i.e. the variable does not exist that is assumed to exist). In this case, I can of course check if the variable exists afterwards. I was just wondering if there is a very general "if there is a javascript error, execute this" type of function. As the browser, of course recognizes any javascript error in the console.

Comment: I would recommend @Niet's answer then

`window.onerror = function(e) { ... }`